# rerender apex:component from actionsupport

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender

i have one apex:component and added it into visualforce page. and from there i want to refresh or say rerender that component based on contact id.

following logic i wrote but its not getting updated based on contact id.

visual force page :

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
       <apex:outputLabel value="Who to Bill"/>
               <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!whoToBillSelected}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!contacts}"/>
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!selectGuestOrMember}" rerender="updateThis"></apex:actionSupport>
               </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:outputPanel id="updateThis" >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Payment Method's"/>
            <c:C62PaymentComponent mode="Choose" showTemporary="false" sObjectId="{!contact_id}">
            </c:C62PaymentComponent>
{!contact_id}
</apex:outputPanel>
```

so when i select any other value from "who to bill" select list i want to refresh "updateThis" output panel. now i have added variable "contact_id" which gives us contact id dynamically.  i printed that as well after component. same variable i passed into component as well. and when i change the value from list then this variable print id of whatever contact i select but component is not getting updated. i want to know if i am doing anything wrong here?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i couldnt find any answer to refresh only component so what i did is used page reference and refreshed the page with setRedirect = false.

this way i got whole page refreshed with no data lost which is already filled on that page and i got to refresh component as well yehheee... :D

following i did in controller when action support call "selectGuestOrMember" this function.

```
public PageReference selectGuestOrMember(){
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/page');
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        return pageRef;
}
```

and it worked for me..